# Adding style to sortable column

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tablesorter

I have this code:

**HTML**

```
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#table").tablesorter();
</script>
```

How can I add special selector to sortable column's  tag?

Comment: I want to add background color to sortable column

Answer (score 0):

Like This

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/js64b/14/)**

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
function SortableTableCtrl() {
        var scope = this;

        // data
        scope.head = {
            a: "Name",
            b: "Surname",
            c: "City"
        };
        scope.body = [{
            a: "Hans",
            b: "Mueller",
            c: "Leipzig"
        }, {
            a: "Dieter",
            b: "Zumpe",
            c: "Berlin"
        }, {
            a: "Bernd",
            b: "Danau",
            c: "Muenchen"
        }];

        scope.sort = {
            column: 'b',
            descending: false
        };

        scope.selectedCls = function(column) {
            return column == scope.sort.column && 'sort-' + scope.sort.descending;
        };

        scope.changeSorting = function(column) {
            var sort = scope.sort;
            if (sort.column == column) {
                sort.descending = !sort.descending;
            } else {
                sort.column = column;
                sort.descending = false;
            }
        };
    }
</script>
```

**[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/vCTHw/11/)**

Answer (score 0):

**Like this?**

I found a [jQuery plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) by searching `tablesorter()`

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} ); 
    } 
);
```

If you are using this plugin, you can then set background-color like this:

```
$("#table").tablesorter().css('background-color','#f00');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) which contains a `columns` widget for styling columns. The widget adds class names to each cell in the column so styling can be done using css. But, it becomes rather slow with very large tables.

```
$(function() {

  $("table").tablesorter({
    theme : 'blue',

    sortList : [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]],

    // initialize zebra striping and column styling of the table
    widgets : ["zebra", "columns"],

    widgetOptions : {
      // change the default column class names
      // primary is the first column sorted, secondary is the second, etc
      columns : [ "primary", "secondary", "tertiary" ],
      // include thead when adding class names
      columns_thead : true,
      // include tfoot when adding class names
      columns_tfoot : true
    }

  });

});
```

Check out the [demo here](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-columns.html).